# Step definition not recognized

Tags: protractor, chai, cucumberjs, scenarios

I am using protractor and cucumber for e2e test.
The scenario outline is like:

```
Scenario Outline: Visit HomeScreen
Given I am on the homescreen
When I do nothing
Then I should see the element with id <elemid>    

Examples:
|elemid|
|scan-sample-image|
|how-to-run|
|navigation-button|
```

My step definition for the "then" part is like:

```
this.Then(/^I should see the element with id \<elemid\>$/, function(id){
//some code      
});
```

However when I call protractor, I see this:

```
Scenario: Visit HomeScreen
V Given I am on the homescreen
V When I do nothing
? Then I should see the element with id scan-sample-image

Scenario: Visit HomeScreen
V Given I am on the homescreen
V When I do nothing
? Then I should see the element with id how-to-run

Scenario: Visit HomeScreen
V Given I am on the homescreen
V When I do nothing
? Then I should see the element with id navigation-button
```

The "Then" is not beying recognized.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not personally used `cucumber` seriously yet, but should not your `Then` definition have this regular expression with a *capturing group* instead:

```
/^I should see the element with id (.*?)$/
```

Comment: the java equivalent for the same is `^I should see the element with id \"([^\"]*)\"$`

Comment: @Ashish Deshmukh: the two quotion marks \" end up in the same problem i.e. the methods were not recognized.

Comment: @alecxe: I had tried to use a regular expression too, however I had used quotion marks \" around it, so that the methods were not found!

Answer (score 0):

Add this `/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/` where you are trying to catch the parameter from feature file. Your code will be

```
this.Then(/^I should see the element with id "([^"]*)"$/, function(id){
//some code      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Gherkin syntax is incorrect, there should be quotes around the dimond brackets

Try changing below line

```
Then I should see the element with id <elemid>
```

to

```
Then I should see the element with id "<elemid>"
```

And then generate steps, it should turn into something like this,

```
this.Then(/^I should see the element with id (.*)$/, function(id){
   //some code      
});
```